# io.socket.emit returns undefined

Tags: jquery, node.js, sockets

I am trying to write a simple response from node to browser to all client and sender itself but i keep on having this error 'emit undefined' what did i do wrong in the process? I know i can use socket.broadcast.emit and socket.emit to achieve my goal but io.socket.emit is much cleaner i think

Here is my code

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var sql = require('mysql');
server.listen(3000);

app.get('/nodeThis', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/sample.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.on('test value', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    if(data === '1') {
        io.socket.emit('test results', { hello: 'Good' });
    } else {
        io.socket.emit('test results', { hello: 'Bad' });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to send the message to just the socket that you received the `test_value` message from?  Or to all connected sockets.

Comment: to all connected sockets i hope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seem OK except following.
You told you like to send every client.

Then change

```
io.socket.emit('test results', { hello: 'Good' });
io.socket.emit('test results', { hello: 'Bad' });
```

To:

```
 io.sockets.emit('test results', { hello: 'Good' });
 io.sockets.emit('test results', { hello: 'Bad' });
```

just to all sockets so io.socket(s) :D

Hope this may help you.